# Diagram of Short exact sequences

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Can someone help me. I want to write morphisms between all objects

```
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
  \begin{array}{*{9}c}
    0 &\Lrightarrow & X & \Lrightarrow & Y & \Lrightarrow & Z & \Lrightarrow & 0\\
    & & \Ldownarrow & & \Ldownarrow & & \Ldownarrow & & \\
    0 &\Lrightarrow & X^' & \Lrightarrow & Y^' & \Lrightarrow & Z^' &  \Lrightarrow & 0
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Sorry, what has your question to do with `tikz-pgf`? And please consider providing a compilable code.

Comment: What are `\Lrightarrow` and `\Ldownarrow`?

Comment: It is compilable in my latex. Do you have another code from titkz-pgf?

Comment: Bernard to be honest, I do not know, I just need to write morphisms between objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here are solutions with `xy` and `tikz-cd`. The idea is the same, think on them as matrices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
  0 \ar[r] & A \ar[d]_-{\alpha} \ar[r]^-{f} & B \ar[d]_-{\beta} \ar[r]^-{g} & C \ar[d]^-{\gamma} \ar[r] & 0 \\
  0 \ar[r] & A' \ar[r]_-{f'} & B' \ar[r]_-{g'} & C' \ar[r] & 0
}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \arrow[r] & A \arrow[d, "\alpha"] \arrow[r, "f"] & B \arrow[d, "\beta"] \arrow[r, "g"] & C \arrow[d, "\gamma"] \arrow[r] & 0 \\
  0 \arrow[r] & A' \arrow[r, "f'"] & B' \arrow[r, "g'"] & C' \ar[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DiegoHavez, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `psmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

   \[
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
    \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1cm, colsep=1.2cm]
    0 & A & B & C & 0 \\
    0 & D & B' & C' & 0
    %% Arrows
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=3pt, shortput=nab, labelsep=1.5pt}
    \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,4}{1,5}\ncline{2,1}{2,2}\ncline{2,4}{2,5}
    \ncline{1,2}{1,3}^{f}\ncline{1,2}{2,2}_{\alpha}
    \ncline{1,3}{1,4}^{g}\ncline{1,3}{2,3}_{\beta}\ncline{1,4}{2,4}_{\gamma}
    \ncline{2,2}{2,3}_{f'}
    \ncline{2,3}{2,4}_{g'}
   \end{psmatrix} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know the meaning of `nc` in `ncline` command? I mean, `line` is clear; `c` maybe for column; and what about `n`?

Comment: `nc` is for `node connection`, as far as I know.

Comment: ahh, makes sense. Nice!